# Limit of the form $0*\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Consider the limit L=$\lim_{x\to\infty}$ $x^2*((\frac{x+1}{x-1})^x-e^2)$.

As $x$ approaches $\infty$, $x^2$ approaches $\infty$ and $(\dfrac{x+1}{x-1})^x$ approaches $e^2$, So we have a $0*\infty$ situation. I tried resolving this with L'hopital, by writing $x^2$ as $1/(1/x^2))$, But it wasnt quite clear with how to proceed further. Another Idea I had was to write out the expansion of $(\dfrac{x+1}{x-1})^x$ by writing it as ($1+\dfrac{2x}{x-1}$)^x, and using the binomial theroem, But that didnt help either.

This was from a high school maths exam and the syllabus DID-NOT include maclaurin/taylor series, so there has to be an easier way. The answer given is $2/3*e^2$

Comment: I wouldn't even say the expression in the limit is well defined. For $x>1$, you have $(1+x)/(1-x) < 0$, and stuff like $y^x$ (for $y<0$ and most values of $x$) is just very badly behaved.

Comment: Yes, it's undefined for $x \geq 1$. If anything approaches $e^2$, then it should be $\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x$.

Comment: You can try to compute the limit of the corresponding _sequence_ to avoid the issues with $a^b$ when $a<0$ and $b$ is not an integer. But even then, the expression oscillates between $-\infty$ and $2e^2/3$ so the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: pardon me, It was indeed supposed to be $x+1/x-1$. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a typo and you need to replace $1-x$ in denominator with $x-1$.

Assuming that this is so we can see that the expression under limit is of the form $x^2(A-B) $ where both $A, B$ tend to same number $e^2$. We can write the expression as $$x^2B\cdot\frac{(A/B) - 1}{\log(A/B)}\cdot\log(A/B)$$ and the fraction in middle tends to $1$ so that the desired limit equals the limit of $$e^2x^2(\log A-\log B) =e^2x^2\left(x\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}-2\right)$$ Putting $x=1/h$ we can see that $h\to 0^{+}$ and the above expression becomes $$e^2\cdot\frac{\log(1+h)-\log(1-h)-2h}{h^3}$$ You can use Taylor series to show the above tends to $2e^2/3$.

I don't think that there is an approach which avoids L'Hospital's Rule, Taylor series or some equivant approach.

If you wish to use integrals you can see that $$\log(1+h)-\log(1-h)-2h=\int_{0}^{h}\left(\frac{2}{1-t^2}-2\right)\,dt$$ which can be further rewritten as $$\int_{0}^{h}\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2}\,dt$$ Putting $t=u^{1/3}$ we can see that the above integral reduces to $$\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{h^3}\frac{du}{1-u^{2/3}}$$ and by fundamental theorem of calculus the above divided by $h^3$ tends to $2/3$ and we get the answer as $2e^2/3$.

Comment: Your "assumption" was indeed correct, I have fixed it. Great, concise answer.

Comment: @satan29: I have provided another approach based on integrals in later part of the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2\left(\left(\frac{x+1}{{x-1}}\right)^x-e^2 \right)= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{[(1+t)/(1-t)]^{1/t}-e^2}{t^2}$$
$f(t)=\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)^{1/t}$ is an even function whose Mclaurin expansion is
$$f(t)=e^2+\frac{2e^2 t^2}{3}+\frac{28 t^4}{45}+ O(t^6)$$
Then $$ L=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^2+(2e^2/3)t^2+O(t^4)-e^2}{t^2}=\frac{2e^2}{3}$$